# Output dynamic_sidebar into PHP

Tags: sidebar

I know

```
 wp_title("",false)
```

Outputs a title for a page into HTML.

How do I do the same for the

```
dynamic_sidebar();
```

?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar

Comment: You want to display name that sidebar was registered with in front end? This is not very common, it is presumed to be for admin side use. Since you need name to call `dynamic_sidebar()` anyway why do you want to do this with code?

Answer (score 1):

As @kaiser pointed out in the comments, the [function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar) for Dynamic_sidebar() is perfectly useful.

On the other hand, if what you'd like to do is add a custom header to a particular sidebar, you could add a text widget to the top of that sidebar in the wp-admin widget area and place your custom title in that.